# $javax.servlet.GenericFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c2c92ce not in same package as lookup class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

[2m2023-01-13 11:57:47.628[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v2.3.4.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2023-01-13 11:57:48.127[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.c.i.InventoryAuthServiceApplication   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The following profiles are active: dev
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:49.552[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:49.720[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 162ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:49.840[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.005[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m BeanFactory id=a848a303-3fd7-3bf5-b275-34c0bdce5a5b
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.700[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9100 (http)
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.711[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.711[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.834[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.834[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2675 ms
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.942[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.942[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:50.953[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mc.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory [0;39m [2m:[0;39m DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@6ce094d0
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.033[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.121[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.131[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m H2 console available at '/h2'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9550/mem:mydb'
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.313[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception starting filter [jwtAuthenticationFilter]

org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException-->$javax.servlet.GenericFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c2c92ce not in same package as lookup class
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:558) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:363) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:108) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.reflect.FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.helper(MethodProxy.java:135) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.init(MethodProxy.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:216) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at com.cg.inventoryauthservice.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a1ef1cb.init() ~[classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4528) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at com.cg.inventoryauthservice.InventoryAuthServiceApplication.main(InventoryAuthServiceApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: $javax.servlet.GenericFilter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7c2c92ce not in same package as lookup class
**  at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleStatics.newIllegalArgumentException(MethodHandleStatics.java:167) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassFile.newInstance(MethodHandles.java:2283) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.makeClassDefiner(MethodHandles.java:2318) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:1843) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:555) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
... 67 common frames omitted

[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.314[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.314[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.317[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.317[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [HikariPool-1 connection adder] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@17.0.4.1/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
java.base@17.0.4.1/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.383[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.443[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.444[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.453[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.468[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2023-01-13 11:57:51.471[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m6868[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at com.cg.inventoryauthservice.InventoryAuthServiceApplication.main(InventoryAuthServiceApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted

Trying to run project with Spring Security unable to boot up !!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if you use jdk17, then adding flags helped me with a similar problem:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
```